# Beset by, beset with

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between the following sentences:

1. Her career was beset **with** difficulties.
2. Her career was beset **by** difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unique to the verb "to be beset", in general the two particles "by" and "with" imply different things.  Consider the difference between these two requests:

> Come stand *by* her.
>
> Come stand *with* her.

*By* implies that you simply stand in the same physical space that she does.  But *with* implies that you and she are standing *together*.  To stand *with* someone connects the two of you much more than just to stand *by* them.

(That being said, the idiom "to stand by" can have [several other meanings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stand+by), which you have to determine from context. English is complicated.)

In the same way there's a subtle difference in the *nuance* between beset *with* and beset *by*.  "With" suggests that the difficulties were *connected* to her career in some way -- that she ran into many problems as a consequence of the job.  "By" suggests the difficulties were *disconnected* from her career, that they were not necessarily related to the job.